# (Un)collapse ALL tagged threads in mutt?

Tags: mutt

I'm trying to configure mutt so that whenever I switch to a folder, it collapses all threads by default, *except* those containing unread messages.

This is the folder hook I've written so far:

```
folder-hook . "push <collapse-all><tag-pattern>~(~N)<enter><tag-prefix-cond><collapse-thread>"
```

- `collapse-all` collapses all threads;
- `tag-pattern: ~(~N)` tags all visible (thread parent) messages belonging to threads containing unread messages;
- `tag-prefix-cond` is supposed to make the next function apply to all tagged messages;
- but it appears `collapse-thread` doesn't respond to the tag prefix (my guess is that's because it's written to act on threads, not messages).

So can this be done? (without writing a patch to mutt, that is?)

Answer (score 1):

I think You do not even need a macro. There are configuration options regarding (un)collapsing.

Try following configuration and comment the macro:

```
set collapse_all = yes 
set uncollapse_new = no # (default is yes)
```

Comment: collapse_all is not a mutt variable.

Comment: You're right. I'm using neomutt and this config options doesn't exist in mutt.